# What GUI for Drawing in LateX Can Do this Drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx, technical-drawing

There are some threads about GUI of TikZ. I have installed several GUI but I cannot find the functionality to do this simple drawing. Which GUI can help me do this?

I am using Lyx.

[image]

Comment: None of the GUIs can draw straight lines, arrows and/or rectangles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I don't think I would use any GUI for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw,thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=0.4cm,outer sep=4pt] at (0,0) (A) {};
 \node[draw,thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=0.4cm,outer sep=4pt] at (6,0) (B) {};
 \draw[thick] (A.north) -- (A.south) node[below] {$t_\mathrm{initial}$};
 \draw[thick] (B.north) -- (B.south) node[below] {$t_\mathrm{final}$};
 \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([yshift=4pt]A.north west) -- ([yshift=4pt]A.north
 east);
 \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([yshift=4pt]B.north west) -- ([yshift=4pt]B.north
 east);
 \draw[thick] (A.center) -- (B.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]